# Could 'Spring RESTful' + 'Java Config' + 'Tests' be used without Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, rest, testing

Can't make tests working with such a configuration.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(value="classpath:app-test.properties")
public class LoginTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private AuthController authController;

    @Test
    public void testOk() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                    .webAppContextSetup(context)
                    .apply(springSecurity())
                    .build();
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/auth")
            .with(httpBasic("u", "p")))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Getting error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: springSecurityFilterChain cannot be null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3383 this may be of use

Comment: @FattySalami it's spring MVC there...

Comment: Isn’t that what your using with SpringRunner and MockMvc? Or is there a different MVC framework your using?

Comment: @FattySalami the question is about not to use Spring MVC. Or may be I havent' got your question...

Comment: what is springSecurity(). I assume it should be something like - new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver(), if not try with this code instead of springSecurity() method.

Comment: @surya it doesnt' accept such arg.
springSecurity() = new SecurityMockMvcConfigurer()

I still can't get the main idea: could spring rest+security be tested without mvc ?

Comment: i tried to explain in the answer. see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see your stacktrace , you can note that this is thrown at
 SecurityMockMvcConfigurer.java (a spring lib class) and if your see the code at that line inside in this class , exception is raised from below code.

```
public static MockMvcConfigurer More ...springSecurity(Filter springSecurityFilterChain) {
    Assert.notNull(springSecurityFilterChain,
    "springSecurityFilterChain cannot be null");
    return new SecurityMockMvcConfigurer(springSecurityFilterChain);
}
```

which means one bean springSecurityFilterChain is needed and that is how  SecurityMockMvcConfigurer is build.

Thus you need to provide this autowired bean,

If you already have this bean , Then make it available

```
@Autowired
FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

@Test
public void testOk() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .webAppContextSetup(context)
        .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
        //.setCustomArgumentResolvers(new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver()) // if you dont have that bean then try with this line and delete above line.
        .build();

    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/auth")
        .with(httpBasic("u", "p")))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```